# iPhone Messages app delete confirmation

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

Whenever I attempt to delete a conversation thread in the Messages app on my iPhone, why is it asking me for confirmation? It used to be just swipe left and delete.

Comment: Which iPhone?  Which version of iOS?  Can you post a screen shot?  It's important to include essential details like this...remember we're not there to look over your shoulder.

Comment: iPhone 6s Plus. 11.3 iOS

Comment: Ya I’m having the same issue. I don’t like it!![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljiMf.png)

Answer (score 3):

It’s a “feature” and currently cannot be disabled. Man I hope they change that.